# hanekeswift remove image from all FormatName

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiimageview, haneke

using Haneke Swift when I set an image to an `UIImageView` (scaled) with the `.hnk_setImageFromUrl` extension function, how can I remove this again from the Cache. 
I've tried:

```
profileImageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string: imageUrl)!)
Shared.imageCache.remove(key: imageUrl!)
```

checking the FileSystem and reading the code it's only removes images from `HanekeGlobals.Cache.OriginalFormatName`
which still leads to cached images in the Auto*aspectfill caches

```
shared-images/auto-160.0x160.0-aspectfill:
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 staff 123123 9 Jan 13:26 https%3A%2F%2Fapi.example.com%2Fpubapi%2Fusers%2Fuser%2Fpicture`
```

Is this expected behavior?

Ofcourse it's always an idea to clear the cache totally 
with

```
Shared.imageCache.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers told me the following:

> You can do:
>
> ```
> Shared.imageCache.remove(key: imageUrl, formatName: profileImageView.hnk_format.name)
> ```
>
> Still, I think we probably should have a `removeFromAll` method.

Comment: it worked for you? i still cannot remove data from cache. should be a simple thing for a library that just set cache.